# How to form a cubic equation with the substitution method?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I had this question:

"Find the cubic equation whose roots are twice the roots of the equation $3x^3 - 2x^2 + 1 = 0$"

In my first attempt, I solved it through the use of simultaneous equations, where I let the cubic equation be: $x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. However, I've been told that there is a more efficient method for higher degree polynomials - and it has been labelled as "The Substitution method".

It involved something like "Let $y = x^2$" then form a new equation using that.
Could someone solve this question and explain how to do it for me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

---

The solution with the substitution method worked like this:

Let $y=2x$,
$x=y/2$ 
then it was substituted back into the given equation.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a root $x$ of $$3x^3-2x^2+1=0$$

If $y=2x$, then $x=\cfrac y 2$ and $$3(\frac y 2)^3-2(\frac y 2)^2+1=0$$

Clear the fractions and you obtain an equation with integer coefficients satisfied by $y$.

The key to the substitution method is to find an expression for $x$ (a root of the original equation) and substitute it into the original equation. It depends on doing the same thing to each of the roots.

Comment: This cleared things up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We want the roots $y_i$ to be $2x_i$. So substitute $\frac{y}{2}$ everywhere for $x$, and simplify if you wish.

Afterwards, if you want the variable name to be $x$, replace $y$ by $x$.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Let the roots of the given equation be $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}$.The new roots will be $2a_{1},2a_{2},2a_{3},2a_{4}$
Now use Vieta' formula. [Vieta's Formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Sum of roots = $2(\sum a_{i})=\dfrac{4}{3}$ and product of roots = $8a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}=-8$

The equation will be : $$x^{3}-\frac{4}{3}x^{2}+\frac{8}{3}=0$$ or, $$3x^{3}-4x^{2}+8=0$$